# Windows IoT error on driver install: Could not start update, (0x8024A10F)

Tags: driver, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I created `.cab` package using a manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/peripheraldrivers

I copied the file, staged the update, but get error on commit:

```
[192.168.1.17]: PS C:\Data\USERS\DefaultAccount\Documents> applyupdate -stage .\Contoso.Drivers.oem6.cab
Microsoft (C) C:\windows\system32\ApplyUpdate.exe
INFO: Start staging .\Contoso.Drivers.oem6.cab
INFO: UpdateStateIdle
INFO: Check status...
INFO: No past issues to report
INFO: ProgressStateNone: 0
INFO: Shared data folder found: C:\Data\ProgramData\USOShared\Data
INFO: Copying file: .\Contoso.Drivers.oem6.cab
INFO: Staging succeeded
SUCCESS: Staging succeeded
[192.168.1.17]: PS C:\Data\USERS\DefaultAccount\Documents> applyupdate -commit
Microsoft (C) C:\windows\system32\ApplyUpdate.exe
INFO: Start commit
INFO: UpdateStateIdle
INFO: Check status...
INFO: No past issues to report
INFO: Starting component installation...
applyupdate : ERROR: Could not start update, (0x8024A10F)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Could no...e, (0x8024A10F):String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

ERROR: Windows Update is already in progress. Please try again after it has finished.
INFO: ProgressStateNone: 0
ERROR: Commit Failed
[192.168.1.17]: PS C:\Data\USERS\DefaultAccount\Documents>
```

Reboot of the device don't perform the update, no new device in device manger in Windows Device Portal...

What can be a problem?

**UPDATE**

The problem is about stack updating process: [Failed to install CAB file as device is in the middle of an update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633924/failed-to-install-cab-file-as-device-is-in-the-middle-of-an-update?noredirect=1#comment96078544_54633924)

**UPDATE**

Here is the header of the `.inf` driver file form PC.

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
Class=Ports
ClassGuid={4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Provider=%PRO%
DriverVer=10/01/2018,3.8.28.0
;DLL Ver=08/29/2017,1.0.0.5
CatalogFile=ser2pl.cat
```

Currently I have two ways to solve the problem:

- To solve update problem
- To use onboard UART port

In the second way I also have problem, I have null in the SerialPort:

```
string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
List<DeviceInformation> list = devices.ToList();
DeviceInformation di = list.First();
serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(di.Id);
```

`serialPort` is `null`
`di.Id` equals: `Id "\\\\?\\ACPI#BCM2836#0#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"  string`
`list.Count` equal `1`

**UPDATE**

Here is the question about problem with onboard UART:

[Unable to open UART port on Windows IoT with Raspberry Pi 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649437/unable-to-open-uart-port-on-windows-iot-with-raspberry-pi-3)

**UPDATE**

I reflashed the device, but have same problem with updates. I have device several hours on, and it still downloads the updates:

> Current OS Version: 10.0.17763.107
>   Downloading updates.
>   Last checked: 2019-02-14 at 08:10

Comment: Where do you get drivers from? PC? Raspberry Pi need drivers for ARM architecture instead of x86.

Comment: It not about drivers, drivers are OK. I installed every thing necessary for conversion. And mentioned the official article from Microsoft, please put attentions. I guess, that USB bus uses it own assembly, process and architecture.

Comment: Can you check from device portal to see what's the update status of the system? And you can flash a new SD card with latest version to see if it works so that determine if this is issue related system update. BTW, do you use the [Sample Driver Package](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit/tree/master/Workspace/Source-arm/BSP/CustomRpi2/Packages/CustomRPi2.GPIO) in the official article? Or how  do you make sure the drivers are OK?

Comment: Yes, device portal is in updating state from 30 January. I think we will need to reflash SD card, but it will take time, currently I guess I will try to use onboard COM port (pins 8 and 10), shortly I will post link to new question here (BTW, thanx for your help!). About Sample Driver Package - I din't tried the Sample, I just prepared my own, see the header of the INF in the update. How can I be  sure? I'm not sure, I just solve problems in th eorder the problems are coming. Currently I try to solve the update problem, for see whether there will be problems with ported driver.

Comment: Hi Olga Pshenichnikova, have you tried the new re-flashed image?

Comment: Hi! As you sow I tried B+ raspberry, and came back to previous version. I have device running for several hour but have same problem with update, it still downloads it: Current OS Version: 10.0.17763.107 Downloading updates. Last checked: 2019-02-14 at 08:10

Comment: Now updates are worked fine, but I still didn't tried to install driver. However I have problem with deploy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723792/failed-to-connect-to-device-192-168-1-17-using-universal-authentication