# Failed to install CAB file as device is in the middle of an update

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-update, windows-iot-core-10

I try to install `.cab` file via Windows Device Portal running on Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows IoT Core 10.
How ever there is eternal update process.
I get error:

```
Failure reason: Failed to install CAB file as device is in the middle of an update.
```

Some other error I get via Power Shell: [Windows IoT error on driver install: Could not start update, (0x8024A10F)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633413/windows-iot-error-on-driver-install-could-not-start-update-0x8024a10f)

I stopped the update service as described here: https://developers.de/blogs/indraneel/archive/2016/04/22/how-to-disable-the-auto-update-on-windows-10-iot-core.aspx and made restart, however it didn't solved the problem.

**UPDATE**

Here a write about the way, I assembled the driver:

[Windows IoT error on driver install: Could not start update, (0x8024A10F)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633413/windows-iot-error-on-driver-install-could-not-start-update-0x8024a10f)

Comment: Please try again after it has finished.Please wait for your device to complete the OS update.

Comment: It updating from 30 January, it stick on the update.

Comment: Which build did you update from?

Comment: In "Device Settings", I see: This is a Windows 10 IoT Core test image designed for prototyping only. If you are looking to commercialize, you must use a custom FFU for optimal security. v.10.0.17134.1

Comment: How did you get the `.cab` file? Is it packaged by yourself?

Comment: Yes, it described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633413/windows-iot-error-on-driver-install-could-not-start-update-0x8024a10f